# CarrierWave: Cannot insert legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, fog, fog-google

Uploading file to google cloud bucket was working fine when we had "Fine-grained" access. Later it is changed to "uniform bucket-level access". Now upload operations are failing with the below error.

invalid: Cannot insert legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access (Google::Apis::ClientError)

Any solutions/suggestions to tackle this issue.

Using 'carrierwave': '1.3.2'

Comment: Same upload is working fine with the "google/cloud/storage" api libraries with uniform access level. But I want to use carrierwave for my usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we set fog_public returns as nil, CarrierWave upload would work with uniform bucket-level access.